# OpenCL Buffer Array - clEnqueueWriteBuffer -36

Tags: c++, opencl

as I'm working on a easy to use `OpenCL` implementation I ran into the error `-36` `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`.  I'm using the `OpenCL C++ Wrapper` for `spec 1.1` with enabled throwing exceptions.
So I have this function - I've commented, what it should do (or what I think it should do..):

```
void createBuffers(std::vector< OpType > arrays) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++) {
            buffer.push_back( cl::Buffer(contextCL, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(OpType)*length)); //creating the buffers depending on how big arrays is - buffer has been declared as cl::vector<cl::Buffer> buffer;

//here the Exception is thrown
            queueCL.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer[i], CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(OpType)*length,arrays[i]); //writing the contents of arrays[i] (arrays[i] is a C Array) to the buffer i

            kernelCL.setArg(i, buffer[i]);
        }
        result_buffer = cl::Buffer(contextCL, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, length*sizeof(OpType));
        kernelCL.setArg(arrays.size(), result_buffer);
    }
```

Should this be able to work? For further information just ask!
Thank you in advance,
- fodinabor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well error -36 is `CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE`. You can't fix it inside the function. The command queue is already not created when you call it.

The real error is elsewhere. It is just showing up there.

Comment: Well I replaced: `cl::CommandQueue queueCL(contextCL, defaultDeviceCL);` with `queueCL = cl::CommandQueue(contextCL, defaultDeviceCL);`
Now getting an Seg Fault from nvopencl.dll but I think this will be fixable

Thank you!

Comment: You need to check each step, context, device, queue, kernels, and then buffer/kernel execution/copy. Otherwise you will have to go back to the beginning of you implementation again to correct errors you did there.

Comment: Thank you, It just worked everything after your Tip!